# How to let a sql query run longer than 2 minutes in microsoft logic apps

Tags: sql, azure, azure-logic-apps

I use microsoft logic apps to build automations, mostly using sql queries.  My issue is that if the SQL query takes longer than 2 minutes that step in the logic app fails.  Any idea how to increase this time horizon?

Comment: I searched for "microsoft logic app long sql query" and found articles such as [Handle stored procedure timeouts in the SQL connector for Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/handle-long-running-stored-procedures-sql-connector). Maybe you needed a better search term?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Logic app inbound requests and the outbound requests which follow the standard asynchronous and synchronous operation pattern which has a [timeout duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config?tabs=azure-portal#timeout-duration) defined for 120 seconds.

One of the workarounds for this is to use Logic Apps Async Response which allows you to keep the Logic Apps engine waiting for a job for much longer by employing this async pattern.

For more information on this, you can refer [How to do an HTTP Async Response pattern work in Logic Apps](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppsAsyncResponseSample)